# ESP32-C3 FLASH encryption using Platformio

Tags: encryption, esp32, esp-idf, flash-memory, platformio

I am trying to encrypt my FLASH on ESP32-C3, but can't seem to find any explanation or examples, how to do that on Platformio using esp-idf framework. Is it possible to encrypt flash and program encrypted mcu using Platformio or is this only possible using native ESP-idf?